# nothing is written to my text file if run from within cron

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

I have a script from within which I write some text to a file. It works fine if I manually i9nvoke it from the shell but it doesn't seem to work prperly if it's invoked from cron. The file is created but nothing gets written to `/tmp/tx_buf`. The script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i Threshold=1000
tmpfile="/tmp/tx_buf"

if [ -e $tmpfile ]
then
        echo "$tmpfile exists, read value"
        typeset -i last=$(cat $tmpfile)
        echo $last
fi
typeset -i val=$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_packets)
echo $val > $tmpfile
declare -i diff=`expr $val - $last`
echo "difference: $diff"
if [[ "$diff" -gt "$Threshold" ]]
then
        echo "music is playing, invoke action"
        `xdotool mousemove_relative 1 1`
else
        echo "no music playing, ignore"
fi
```

Why is this, I'm wondering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do some troubleshooting in the following way:

Change the script header like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 1>/tmp/$0.log 2>&1
set -x

...insert the rest of you script here....
```

After cron was starting you script you should find a file called

```
/tmp/.log
```

This should give details about what was going on during runtime.